# How to change rows to columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, rows

I have a query that is displaying some information from various tables in a database.

```
SELECT    
                c.Name,
                jp.PieceType,
                jp.Qty
        FROM customer c
        LEFT JOIN job_new jn ON c.JobID = jn.ID
        LEFT JOIN job_pieces jp ON c.JobID = jp.JobID
        WHERE c.Company_ID = 123
        GROUP BY c.ID
```

I created the database on sqlfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13230/8

Each company can have many piece types but right now the query only displays one type even though more exist. In the sqlfiddle database you can see company 123 has 3 PieceTypes.
[image]

So I want to display the piece types as columns instead of rows.
I want the PieceTypes to be displayed in separate columns like this:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey try this for pivoting of table: [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13230/15)

```
set @sql = null;
select
  group_concat(distinct
    concat(
      'max(case when PieceType = ''',
      PieceType,
      ''' then Qty end) AS ',
      concat(PieceType)
    )
  ) into @sql
from customer c
        LEFT JOIN job_new jn ON c.JobID = jn.ID
        LEFT JOIN job_pieces jp ON c.JobID = jp.JobID
        WHERE c.Company_ID = 123;

set @sql = concat('select c.Name,', @sql, ' FROM customer c
        LEFT JOIN job_new jn ON c.JobID = jn.ID
        LEFT JOIN job_pieces jp ON c.JobID = jp.JobID
        WHERE c.Company_ID = 123
        GROUP BY c.ID
');

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;
```

Comment: yes that works thanks. But why are the LEFT JOIN lines there twice?

Comment: Actually your data is conditional for group therefore this joins is used there

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT c.Name, group_concat(jp.PieceType) as piecetypes,
        group_concat(jp.Qty) as qtys
FROM customer c LEFT JOIN
     job_new jn
     ON c.JobID = jn.ID LEFT JOIN
     job_pieces jp
     ON c.JobID = jp.JobID
WHERE c.Company_ID = 123
GROUP BY c.ID;
```

Your original query has a major no-no.  You have columns in the `SELECT` that are not in the `GROUP BY`.  MySQL extends `GROUP BY` to allow this behavior.  But, basically, you should never use it.  Maybe there is some good use when you *really* know what you are doing, but no other databases support this extension.  And, MySQL is making the `GROUP BY` ANSI-compliant in version 5.7.5.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I would like the PieceTypes to be in separate columns, not all together in one. I have edited my question to make it more clear what I am trying to do